# Regex not matching two chars when found together

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

So i have an assignment where i have to parse an HTML file using flex.
My problem is: one of the tags i'm interested in is the tag:

`<p> some random text </p>`

my problem is: how can i tell the flex to not match `<p> and </p>` but to match the < or the / or the p when found individually. 
thank you in advance

Comment: What tokens do you expect from `<p> some random text </p>`? Please answer precisely. And what patterns are you using which provide a different tokenisation?

Comment: i expect it to match with everything inside that piece of text, except when i find the pattern </p>.

Comment: Flex partitions the input into tokens. *Every* input character belongs to some token (even if some tokens might be disregarded after they are identified). So what is `<p>`? One token? Three tokens? What about `</p>`? One token? Three tokens? Four tokens? What about `<b>` inside the paragraph text? You cannot write a flex description without being able to answer at that level of detail.